# How do I convert JSON from a file into an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am having trouble parsing JSON. The JSON is properly getting read (as seen in the console), however, I am unable to get the array to save any of the data. I have looked at similar questions but none of them seemed to help my problem. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
function getArray(){
    return $.getJSON('testJSON.json');
}

getArray().done(function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(key, val) {

            words.push(key);
        console.log(key);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you use `words`?

Comment: As Blender pointed out, you might be missing a `var words = []` somewhere, so that you are able to use it as an array later.  Then again, if you are seeing something on the console, `words` should already be defined.

Comment: Would JSON.parse() method work? e.g. var myArray = JSON.parse(json).

Comment: @CiaranG Yup, it looks like JSON.parse() does what I want! I'm having a parsing error with one of the keys now, but I'll ask that in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.parse() seems to be what you're looking for. I'll show how I used it in my project:

I used the jQuery get function to make a HTTP request, then I used JSON.stringify to convert the returned data to a string. I'm not sure if that was necessary for parsing it, or whether I done that so I could store the data in the HTML5 LocalStorage.

e.g.

```
    var treasureHuntString = JSON.stringify(data)
    var treasureHunt = JSON.parse(treasureHuntString);
```

And from thereafter, I could access all the properties within the treasureHunt object. I also made use of browser debugging to be able to see the structure of the object, as it was a little different to what I had expected.